# Magento 2 Remove JS added with requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, requirejs-config.js

**Edit**

So after removing the pub/static folder and also removing the .htaccess file with it and breaking my site I'm finally back to where I was.

Still having issues with JS files that don't exist but were included with requirejs-config.js.

[image]

I've tried several solutions yet nothing is working. The way I added the custom JS files was by creating a requirejs-config.js file in my theme folder, and then mapping the paths to the files inside. I then included them in the default_head_blocks.xml file. But now that I've deleted the JS files, and removed the requirejs-config.js file, and also removed them from the default_head_blocks.xml file I get these errors in the screenshot above.

Comment: Have you removed them from requireconfig-js?

Comment: if you removed the files from requireconfig-js you have to clear the pub/static dir and either `setup:di:compile` if **production** more or just refresh page if **developer** mode

Comment: I cleared out the pub/static directory, but now my site is broken. I've tried static-content:deploy, setup:di:compile, flushing the cache and reindexing. Nothings working...

Answer (score 1):

Magento merges all the `requirejs-config.js` from all the enabled modules into a single `requirejs-config.js` and places it in `pub/static/area/vendor/theme/locale` ex: `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US`

You have to remove the entry from this file.
If you are in developer mode just delete this file and Magento will recreate it on page refresh.
If you are in production mode run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

You can run this command for your particular theme, area and locale as follows

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --language en_US --theme Magento/luma --area frontend
```

More on above command : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html